# Python Selenium webdriver send keys on text field?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textfield

This is the HTML code for the text field:

```
<div tabindex="-1" class="_2bXVy"><div tabindex="-1" class="_3F6QL _2WovP">
    <div class="_39LWd" style="visibility: visible;">Type a message</div>
    <div class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text" contenteditable="true" data-tab="1" dir="ltr" spellcheck="true"></div>
</div>
```

This is my python program which should allow the user to type into the field:

```
msg_box = driver.find_element_by_Id('')
msg_box.send_keys(messege)
```

The text field:
[image: Here is the text field]

**How do i select the text field in python (msg_box = driver.find_element_by)?**

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If class "_2S1VP" is unique on the page, you can select by class, as there is no ID attribute for that element:

```
 driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_2S1VP");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the xml.find method to search using xpath? Depending on your xml library there may be other methods such as lxml's `xpath`

```
xpath = './/div[@class="_2S1VP copyable-text selectable-text"][@contenteditable="true"][@data-tab="1"]'

reply = driver.find(xpath)
```